# Firebase function - Push Notification using Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

i am new to Firebase and firestore

I want to send push notification  in firebase-cloud firestore

i am having a collection chat . and if a new document  is inserted to the  i want to sent a notification to the FCM token details

my Chat  document is shown below
[image: chatcollection]

my token collection ( collection name -user_info)

[image: user_info]

my requirement is if a new record is added to the chat collection then i want a trigger excecute and
need to send the push notification to the user ( user details ans fcm details selected from user_info table, the corresponding user id is selected from the memberIds from the new document)

means need to activate a triggers

i found some document related to node.js but i am not familiar with node
i want to know is it possible to create the trigger and function using python ?

how can i do it with python ?

Comment: Hey, from this documentation [1] it seems like you can trigger the function from GCP to firestore. You can also find the code sample here. 

[1] https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#functions_firebase_firestore-python

Comment: @AmitS  thank you for your replay. Here how can i get the documents and collection details and how can i use that one